# Raster calculator ERROR 000539 when converting values to be from 0-1 using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator, error-000539

[image]

I am getting this error when trying to make values of GHI from 0-1
I only add a layer then I run the raster calculator as attached.

This is my code :

```
 ("Global horizontal irradiation"  -  "Global horizontal irradiation".minimum) / ("Global horizontal irradiation".maximum - "Global horizontal irradiation".minimum)
```

> ERROR 000539: Traceback (most recent call last): File "", line 1, in  File "", line 8, in rcexec_DC684390_0C54_4F14_9EBF_B34DF3F2E1B1 RuntimeError: Unspecified error Failed to execute (RasterCalculator).

Comment: Ensure you run the calculate statistics tool before attempting to use raster.minumum and .maximum properties.

Comment: Spaces in your raster name? In ArcGIS Desktop your calculation will only work if you convert the raster layer to a raster or describe object: ("Global horizontal irradiation"  -  arcpy.Raster("Global horizontal irradiation").minimum) / (arcpy.Raster("Global horizontal irradiation").maximum - arcpy.Raster("Global horizontal irradiation").minimum) as maximum and minimum properties don't exist for a string. Raster maximum and minimum return None if the statistics aren't built which will cause an unspecified error as user2856 notes.

Answer (score 1):

There are many reasons you can get this error, but here are some of the most common:

1. Rasters do not have same extent or scale
2. Rasters not in same geodatabase
3. Rasters do not share same projection
4. Output filename too long
5. "Spatial Analyst" extension has not been enabled

Comment: how to solve these points ?

Comment: You need to figure out which one of these may apply to you. I would look at them one at a time and see if each is applicable to your dataset. The last two (4 & 5) are very easy to check by shortening the output filename (less than 10 characters) and enabling spatial analyst (https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/spatial-analyst/enabling-the-spatial-analyst-extension.htm)

Comment: 1, 2, and 3 don't apply because it's all the same raster mentioned 4 times. 4 might apply but this is going to the user's Default.gdb and the path looks good in that respect provided the user is logged in as *administrator* otherwise you'd get error 001250 https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/tool-errors-and-warnings/001001-010000/tool-errors-and-warnings-01226-01250-001250.htm. 5 does not apply as that would throw error 010096 https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/tool-errors-and-warnings/010001-020000/tool-errors-and-warnings-10076-10100-010096.htm